# How to remove ANSI control chars (VT100) from a Java String

Tags: java, jsch, ansi-escape, vt100

I am working with automation and using Jsch to connect to remote boxes and automate some tasks.

I am having problem parsing the command results because sometimes they come with [ANSI Control chars](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

I've already saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205837/how-to-remove-colors-etc-from-ssh-output) and [this other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) but it does not provide any library to do that. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, if there is any. And I don't feel confident with those answers.

Right now, I am trying this, but I am not really sure it's complete enough.

```
reply = reply.replaceAll("\\[..;..[m]|\\[.{0,2}[m]|\\(Page \\d+\\)|\u001B\\[[K]|\u001B|\u000F", "");
```

How to remove ANSI control chars (VT100) from a Java String?

Comment: A side comment that I have created an Expect-like library that supports filtering out the input, such as ANSI control characters, out-of-the-box. Could give it a try. Link: https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/expectit

Comment: hey, I will surely take a look on that! it's apache 2 license, is it ok if I copy a snippet of your code and add to my solution?

Comment: Sure! It is Apache 2 :-). If you have any feedback post a message to the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/java-expectit .

Comment: I've been working with expectJ for a year, only because the alternatives could not deal with expect interact(). I've saw your solution briefly but it looks like a big improvement, full of interesting ideas. I wonder if the new closure syntax will allow java developers to have an even more powerful expect implementation. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: thanks. I have created GitHub issues to add support for interact() method and Java 8 lambdas.

Comment: here is a working example of the ExpectIt interact support: https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expect-java8/src/main/java/net/sf/expectit/java8/Java8Example.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most ANSI VT100 sequences have the format `ESC` `[`, optionally followed by a number or by two numbers separated by `;`, followed by some character that is not a digit or `;`.  So something like

```
reply = reply.replaceAll("\u001B\\[[\\d;]*[^\\d;]","");
```

or

```
reply = reply.replaceAll("\\e\\[[\\d;]*[^\\d;]","");  // \e matches escape character
```

should catch most of them, I think.  There may be other cases that you could add individually. (I have not tested this.)

Some of the alternatives in the regex you posted start with `\\[`, rather than the escape character, which may mean that you could be deleting some text you're not supposed to delete, or deleting part of a control sequence but leaving the ESC character in.

Comment: The format of Control Sequences is specified in section 5.4 of the ECMA-48 standard, which is freely available (at least the 5th edition, dated June 1991).

Comment: And it's basically `(\x1b\x5b|\x9b)[\x30-\x3f]*[\x20-\x2f]*[\x40-\x7e]`

Comment: most, but not all